# How to render action from another action inside same controller and pass parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am writing an application that needs to pass parameters or data to another action so that i break down the controller actions into manageable pieces. Whats the best way to do that? To test my code i was issuing a redirect_to

```
new_calendar_account = {
        calendar_account: {
          provider: "google",
          access_token: auth_client.access_token,
          refresh_token: auth_client.refresh_token,
          token_expires_at: token_expiry
        }
      }

redirect_to new_calendar_account_path(new_calendar_account)
```

but its a GET request and i want a POST request and i read that it is not possible.

Thus is it possible to render another action and pass parameters in? Or is best if i make a model method to contain all the code in one place?

Answer (score 0):

You could just call the other action like a function name from an action.
For passing parameters you could just use instance variables.

```
def action_one
  @params = params
  action_two # to execute the code from action_two
  render action: :action_two and return # to render view of action_two
end 

def action_two
  @params ||= params
  # work with passed @params 
end
```

Comment: hey if i do not want to render anything does this still work?

Comment: sure if you skip the render action part it just finishes what action_one does

Comment: now that i think about it defining @params should not even be necessary as the original params from action_one should be accesible by action_two regardless.

Comment: You could split the logic of your application into private methods in the controller and just use those from your actions. But tbh i'd put them into the controller's Helper if possible. Even though i'm using this pattern i described in production code myself.

Comment: hmm i realised the action requires a redirect (making an oauth2 from google). hmm so i just need a place to save the data and retrieve them later.